# How to get labels ids in Keras when training on multiple classes?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm using [`flow_from_directory`](http://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) to get the training set from a folder with the following structure:

```
train
  class1
  class2
  class3
  ...
```

The generator is called as it follows:

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory( 
        train_data_dir,                              
        target_size=(img_height, img_width),         
        batch_size=32,                               
        class_mode='categorical')
```

I am not setting the argument `classes`, but I was expecting to get the labels in alphabetical order.

> **classes**: optional list of class subdirectories (e.g. `['dogs', 'cats']`). Default: None. If not provided, the list of classes will be automatically inferred (and the order of the classes, which will map to the label indices, will be alphanumeric).

However, when I classify the training images (for checking which labels are being returned), I'm don't get any specific ordering. The training goes well (accuracy of ~85%), and there is a consistency with the output labels when classifying images from the same class.

How can I infer the labels numbers generated by `flow_from_directory` and map them to the classes?

Comment: This issue was fixed by [this pull-request](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/pull/3052).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can see which class correspond to which integer looking at the variable `ImageDataGenerator.class_indices`

Here is an example on how to use it

```
    def build(source=None):
        datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
        data_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        source,  # this is the target directory
        target_size=(150, 150),  # all images will be resized to 150x150
        batch_size=11,
        class_mode='sparse')
        class_dictionary = data_generator.class_indices
    return data_generator, class_dictionary
```

Comment: I get the error:  'ImageDataGenerator' object has no attribute 'class_indices'

Comment: it may go without saying, but if you do not want the class_dictionary in this case to be returned automatically when running the `build()` function, you can do:  `global class_dictionary`, then `class_dictionary = data_generator.class_indices` which will allow you to access class_dictionary globally.

Comment: Is there anyway to get the class ids when loading a trained model with load_model? I am using a pre trained model that I got from the web.